Раставить текст по столбцам csv
Стоит такая задача.
Есть текст. Текст нужно распределить по столбцам exel. Столбцы; Название компании, Имя и фамилия, Адрес, номер телефона, электронная почта. Сложность в том что текст может начинаться с алфавита, потом номера страницы и далее выше перечисленное(столбцы которые указывал выше.). Пример текста ниже(кусок текста).
Пока что хватило знаний написать вот эту часть. Заранее спасибо.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
 

url = "https://fliphtml5.com/cmxpr/dlsm/2023_Membership_Directory/"
 
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
tear = soup.find_all('p')
 
with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for  line in tear:
        file.write(line.text + '\n')



C
C Can Store Inc.
Jessica Fielding
#16 11010 46th St SE
Calgary, AB T2C 4Z5
Canada
(403) 452-8889
[email protected]
Bobbi Malana
#16 11010 46th St SE
Calgary, AB T2C 4Z5
Canada
(403) 452-8889
[email protected]
Mel Malana
#16 11010 46th St SE
Calgary, AB T2C 4Z5
Canada
(403) 452-8889
[email protected]
23
Calida Inc.
David Potvin
173, rue Joseph-Gagne Nord
La Baie, QC G7B 4T2
Canada
(418) 718-3130
[email protected]
Marie-Pier Simard
173, rue Joseph-Gagne Nord
La Baie, QC G7B 4T2
Canada
(418) 290-8051
[email protected]
D
D. Edward Leasing Company
Douglas Dively
250 Seanor Road
Windber, PA 15963
(800) 635-8756
[email protected]
Brian Mowery
250 Seanor Road
Windber, PA 15963
(814) 467-5434
[email protected]
Crossroads Trailer Rental
John Bransford
2621 Corner Rock Road
Mian-Midlothian, VA 23113
(804) 378-6222
[email protected]
CS Leasing
Vanessa Garcia
16945 Northchase Drive, Ste 2140
Houston, TX 77060
(28) 137-7200
[email protected]
Rick Reid
14510 Beaumont Highway
Houston, TX 77049
(832) 418-2499
[email protected]
CSI Group LLC
Heidi Gibert
1212 Hancock St
Suite 305
Quincy, MA 02169
(617) 845-5249
[email protected]
Stephan Howard
1212 Hancock St
Suite 305
Quincy, MA 02169
(617) 797-9766
[email protected]


что значит "с алфавита"? приведите пример "лишних" строк.

Строки которые начинаются с одной буквы.

ваша структура еще сложнее, чем вы описали: у вас разное количество строк данных для США и Канады, некоторые адреса разбиты на две строки, название компании - одно на список сотрудников. Короче, очень нетривиальный шаблон данных.  я рекомендовал бы собирать данные на странице не просто списком, а словарем - ключ - значение. это бы в разы упростило работу.
